# How does google map detect real-time road accident when computing shortest path?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map for a logistics vehicle routing app.
Now I encounter 2 problems:

1. google map can find shortest path between any 2 given coordinate. But it is usually for a private car. Sometimes the path for a large logistics truck is different from a private car
2. I know google can display real-time traffic. But if we detect a specific event for logistics truck on a certain road and this event has not been detected by google map, the shortest path computed by google map may be unpractical for truck drivers

I am a rookie for google map and javascript. Can anyone tell me how google handle these 2 problems?
Thx.

Comment: I would guess someone told them

Comment: I reformat the text.....

Answer (score 0):

Well honestly google maps does not deal with logistics for trucks. So the truth is that they do not handle either of these problems. Which is why people exist who deal with the logistics for trucks. Google maps is mainly for the average human, not for truckers or companies or logistics. But if you wanted to solve these problems you might be able to integrate google maps into your very own logistics system for truckers, were you write the code that would find the best path with trucks in mind/ keeping in mind traffic. I assume you are asking how to integrate these two together, which is a slightly longer bigger problem that you will have to solve on your own. But I do suggest looking up trucking logistic systems to get a better idea of how people and similar programs currently solve these problems, it will be a good starting point.

Comment: Zoe, your answer makes me clear of my question. Your suggestion is also very helpful. As for current logistics company, they sometimes use vector graph (say, an update-to-date *.shp) for their routing. Maybe I can try to do sth. using google map. Well, thanks again!